# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute 'Russian Federation'):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Getting a very strange error when running reduce on an activemodel relation.  It seems like calling "c.name" in my reduce code causes the error. c.name returns the string "Russian Federation".  Am I using reduce incorrectly?

Here is the error:

```
[2014-03-17T21:12:40.174655 #9240] FATAL -- :
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `Russian Federation'):
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:96:in `block in pluck_countries'
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:96:in `pluck_countries'
```

Larger stacktrace from the console:

```
@third_party_countries.reduce(@hsh) {|hsh, c| hsh[c.name] = ThirdPartyShipping.first }
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `Russian Federation'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:47:in `write_attribute'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:70:in `write_attribute'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:341:in `[]='
from (irb):3:in `block in irb_binding'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:63:in `each'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:63:in `reduce'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:63:in `method_missing'
from (irb):3
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /var/www/html/babiators.com/landf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is the code:

```
@third_party_countries = Country.third_party_countries

@hsh = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
@third_party_countries.reduce(@hsh) {|hsh, c| hsh[c.name] = c.third_party_shipping }
```

Country schema:

```
create_table "countries", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.float    "shipping_rate"
  t.integer  "third_party_shipping_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "product_id"
end
```

Country model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :third_party_shipping
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  has_many :addresses

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  before_create :init
  after_initialize :init

  scope :shippable, -> { where(third_party_shipping_id: nil) }
  scope :third_party_countries, -> { where.not(third_party_shipping_id: nil) }

  def shipping_price 
    self.shipping_rate * 100
  end

  def free_shipping
    self.shipping_rate <= 0 and self.third_party_shipping_id.nil?
  end

  def paid_shipping
    !self.free_shipping
  end

  def shipping_display
    if self.free_shipping
      "free"
    elsif self.paid_shipping
      self.shipping_rate      
    end
   end

  private
  def init
    if self.shipping_rate.blank? 
      self.shipping_rate = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe hsh is the return of previous block, so can you try: `@third_party_countries.reduce(@hsh) {|hsh, c| hsh[c.name] = c.third_party_shipping; hsh }` and see if works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're declaring `@hsh` outside the loop, you have no need of the extra complexity introduced by `inject`/`reduce`. Just use `each`:

```
@hsh = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
@third_party_countries.each{ |c| @hsh[c.name] = c.third_party_shipping }
```

The problem with your existing code is that, with `inject`/`reduce`, the return value of the block is passed as the first argument to the next invocation. You need to return `hsh` from your block, otherwise the value of `c.third_party_shipping` is passed as `hsh` to the next invocation, and you're effectively doing `c.third_party_shipping[c.name]`.

You *could* make it work by returning `hsh`...

```
@third_party_countries.reduce(@hsh) do |hsh, c|
   hsh[c.name] = c.third_party_shipping
   hsh
end
```

But you shouldn't. You don't need this functionality. [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is the correct method to use:

```
@hsh = @third_party_countries.each_with_object(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |hsh, c|
   hsh[c.name] = c.third_party_shipping
end
```

You could also just `map` the collection to an array, and initialize your hash with that array:

```
@hsh = HashWithIndifferentAccess[@third_party_countries.map { |c| [c.name, c.third_party_shipping] }]
```

This relies on the ability to freely convert between arrays and hashes. The array `[[a, b], [c, d]]` converts to the hash `{ a => b, c => d }`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I was just about to update this saying that I was using reduce incorrectly. When using reduce the accumulator is changed based on the return value of the code block. Just as you mentioned.